# lava lamp menu url not working

Tags: jquery, url, lavalamp

I have a problem with my lava lamp script. generally speaking - URLs are not working. they seem ok in html, so I assume it must be a jQuery code which locks everything inside the page. Could you please take a look and let me know what is wrong with it? This issue drives me mad. Thanks.
HTML Code here  - looks ok to me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".menu-lava").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout",
            speed: 700,
            click: function(event, menuItem) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>


    <ul class="menu-lava">
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="corporate-events.html">Corporate Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="private-parties.html">Private Parties</a></li>
        <li><a href="av-equipment-hire.html">AV Equipment Hire</a></li>
        <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Then the actual page with links to .js files in source:
[LINK TO THE ACTUAL PAGE](http://www.tucadomusic.co.uk/ave/test.html)  - **please see the source code and jquery.lavalamp.min.js - this may be a problematic code**

Comment: I have seen a similar topic but it wasn't sorted. I hope this one will be. Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: please provide the relevant jquery code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning `false`, you prevent the default behavior of the link from occurring:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu-lava").lavaLamp({
        fx: "backout",
        speed: 700,
        click: function(event, menuItem) {
            return false;  // <--- Right here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hah! great job @Blender thanks a lot. works fine now. I have changed false to true and it works. Good man :)

Comment: Should I remove "return false;" or change it to "return true;" or doesn't matter?

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski: Just don't `return` anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(function() {
        $(".menu-lava").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout",
            speed: 700,
            click: function(event, menuItem) {
                return false;//prevents default
            }
        });
    });
```

I think `return false` is the problem. It prevents the default action.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the problem. Should I remove "return false;" or change it to "return true;" or doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the 'return false' in your click event.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the problem. Should I remove "return false;" or change it to "return true;" or doesn't matter?